# behavior of awk in read line

Tags: bash, awk

```
 $ cat file
 11 asasaw121
 12 saasks122
 13 sasjaks22

 $ cat no
 while read line
 do
 var=$(awk '{print $1}' $line)
 echo $var
 done<file

 $ cat yes
 while read line
 do
 var=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
 echo $var
 done<file

 $ sh no
 awk: can't open file 11
 source line number 1

 awk: can't open file 12
 source line number 1

 awk: can't open file 13
 source line number 1

 $ sh yes
 11
 12
 13
```

Why doesn't the first one work? What does awk expect to find in $1 in it? I think understanding this will help me avoid numerous scripting problems.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` always expects a file name as input

In following, `$line` is string not a file.

```
 var=$(awk '{print $1}' $line)
```

You could say *(Note double quotes around variable)*

```
 var=$(awk '{print $1}' <<<"$line")
```

Answer (score 2):

> `Why doesn't the first one work?`

Because of this line:

```
var=$(awk '{print $1}' $line)
```

Which assumes `$line` is a file.

You can make it:

```
var=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
```

OR

```
var=$(awk '{print $1}' <<< "$line")
```

Comment: I need to enter `#define SERVER@"http://10.35.42.54/ms0.8"` to a particular line. How can I achieve this using `awk` or `sed`?

Comment: Sorry achieve what? What are you trying to extract from `#define SERVER@"http://10.35.42.54/ms0.8` line?

Comment: Just need to place this string at line 50 of a particualr text file..That's it.

Comment: This gives me an error `sed: 1: "50s/.*/#define SERVER@" ...": bad flag in substitute command: '/'`

Comment: It works ..But it only prints the changes in terminal. The file remains the same. How can I save the file?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $1}' $line
                 ^^ awk expects to see a file path or list of file paths here
                    what it is getting from you is the actual file line
```

What you want to do is pipe the line into `awk` as you do in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

You got the answers to your specific questions but I'm not sure it's clear that you would never actually do any of the above.

To print the first field from a file you'd either do this:

```
while IFS= read -r first rest
do
    printf "%s\n" "$first"

done < file
```

or this:

```
awk '{print $1}' file
```

or this:

```
cut -d ' ' -f1 <file
```

The shell loop would NOT be recommended.